# How to change MSISDN on USIM Card

Tags: gsm, at-command, sim800, usim

I bought new USIM Card. It has not MSISDN written in the MSISDN list (Phone storage = "ON").
I tried to write MSISDN to the USIM card using AT commands of the modem (SIM800X GSM/GPRS HAT).

```
AT+CPBS=?
+CPBS: ("SM","ME","ON","FD")

AT+CPBS="ON"
AT+CPBS="ON"
OK

AT+CPBS?
AT+CPBS?
+CPBS: "ON",0,3

OK

AT+CPBW=,"+380501234567",145,""
AT+CPBW=,"+380501234567",145,""
ERROR
```

How can I to find out the reason of the error? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting extended error response (`AT+CMEE=2`) and see if it gives any more descriptive error response.

Comment: I tried another SIM Card. It works correctly. I think the probem was that SIM card did not allow to change files.